# Postgres: cache lookup failed for type 5308416

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb, npgsql

When inserting data into a Postgres (timescaledb hyper)table, the following error occurs approximately every 1-5 seconds.

```
ERROR:  cache lookup failed for type 5308416
```

I'm attempting to find what this type is in order to debug further. I've tried looking in the following places but all return zero results:

```sql
select * from pg_class where oid = 5308416;
select * from pg_collation where oid = 5308416;
select * from pg_ts_config where oid = 5308416;
select * from pg_ts_dict where oid = 5308416;
select * from pg_namespace where oid = 5308416;
select * from pg_operator where oid = 5308416;
select * from pg_proc where oid = 5308416;
select * from pg_type where oid = 5308416;
```

The query I'm running looks as follows:

```sql
INSERT INTO "import" AS "T"
  ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af", "ag", "ah", "ai", "aj", "ak", "al", "am", "an", "ao", "ap", "aq", "ar", "as", "at", "au", "av", "aw", "ax", "ay", "az", "ba", "bb") 
VALUES
  ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31, $32, $33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38, $39, $40, $41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $50, $51, $52, $53, $54),
  ($55, $56, $57, $58, $59, $60, $61, $62, $63, $64, $65, $66, $67, $68, $69, $70, $71, $72, $73, $74, $75, $76, $77, $78, $79, $80, $81, $82, $83, $84, $85, $86, $87, $88, $89, $90, $91, $92, $93, $94, $95, $96, $97, $98, $99, $100, $101, $102, $103, $104, $105, $106, $107, $108),
  -- omitted 22 statements
  ($1297, $1298, $1299, $1300, $1301, $1302, $1303, $1304, $1305, $1306, $1307, $1308, $1309, $1310, $1311, $1312, $1313, $1314, $1315, $1316, $1317, $1318, $1319, $1320, $1321, $1322, $1323, $1324, $1325, $1326, $1327, $1328, $1329, $1330, $1331, $1332, $1333, $1334, $1335, $1336, $1337, $1338, $1339, $1340, $1341, $1342, $1343, $1344, $1345, $1346, $1347, $1348, $1349, $1350)
ON CONFLICT ("a", "b", "c", "d") DO NOTHING
```

When retried, the statement inserts as expected.

Where should I look to find the referenced type `5308416`? This type number is consistent in the logs over several days.

For clarity, this is running from a dotnet 8 host, using npgsql.

Comment: Just a guess, but it could be an index corruption. You can try to fool the Optimizer to do a table scan with: select * from pg_type where oid +1= 5308417 or similar and see if that helps. If it does you can rebuild the index

Comment: thanks for the tip @Lennart-SlavaUkraini. Unfortunately the syntax above doesnt run in pgadmin. I've tried to rebuild the index (table?) although I receive the error: must be owner of table pg_type. The owner is azuresa as this using Azure Postgres.

Comment: sorry, was on my phone when commenting. You may have to change it to `... WHERE oid::int + 1 = 5308417`. Did you try `REINDEX TABLE pg_type;`?

Comment: I've opened a support ticket with Microsoft. The `pg_type` table is owned by the `azuresu` account which I'm unable to access. Unless there's a trick to reindex by another means?

Comment: Ran a reindex on the whole database (Azure allow this) and the following were reindexed: `pg_type_oid_index`, `pg_type_typname_nsp_index`, table `pg_catalog.pg_type`. Unfortunately the same issue as above is still present.

Comment: Provoke the error using `psql`, then run `\errverbose` to show where in the code the error is thrown.